# how to give runtime input from qt creator to external jar file

Tags: qt, jar, executable-jar

i searched on this topic but dint get solution.

I am developing qt widgets application to run external jar file and display the jar output on qt gui touch diaplay.
In such a way my external jar file,executed while user given runtime input then process and print the output.(Both read and write)
Here, i executed jar file using QProcess. Process (jar execution) started running, waiting for user input. I cannot give runtime input to my external jar file through both qt console and terminal window. please suggest how to write input and read output back from external jar file through qt.

This is our jar (sample.jar) contained java application file (.java). Export this .java file as executable sample.jar file.

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RuntimeInput {

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Reading jar file");

    System.out.println("Enter Consumer No: ");

    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = inputReader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hi " + name);
``` 
}
}
````

**Expected Qt output:**

Run executable jar in cmd window getting like this,

D:>java -jar sample.jar

Reading jar file
Enter Consumer No:
124569896
Hi 124569896

```
mainwindow.cpp 

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QTextStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

        cmd = new QProcess(this);

        connect( cmd, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(handleReadStandardError()) );

        connect( cmd, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(handleReadStandardOutput()) );

        QStringList arguments;
        arguments << "-jar" << "D:\\sample.jar";

        cmd->start("java",  arguments, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

        //cmd->execute("java -jar D:\\sample.jar");

        if ( cmd->state() == QProcess::NotRunning ) {
           qDebug() << "The process is not running.It exits";
        }
        else if ( cmd->state() == QProcess::Starting ) {
            qDebug() << "The process is started, but the program has not yet been invoked.";
        }else if ( cmd->state() == QProcess::Running ) {
            qDebug() << "The process is running and is ready for reading and writing.";
        }

        if (!cmd->waitForStarted())  {
           qDebug() << "Not yet started";

        }

}

void MainWindow::handleReadStandardError()
{
    QByteArray data = cmd->readAllStandardError();
    qDebug() << data;
    ui->textEdit->append(QString(data));
}

void MainWindow::handleReadStandardOutput()
{
   QByteArray data = cmd->readAllStandardOutput();
   qDebug() << "Data:\n" << data << endl;
   ui->textEdit->append(QString(data));

}
```

**QT Console output:**

Starting D:\ANNIE\QT Workspace\build-Samplewrite-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Samplewrite.exe...
The process is running and is ready for reading and writing.
Data:

"Reading jar file \r\n
Enter Consumer No: \r\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) inherits from [OIODevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html), so you can use the [write()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) function to write data to it's standard input:

```
cmd->write("124569896\n");
```

Comment: We tried this solution and i can able to write data now, But my query is When i type User input in Qt Console window, dont know how to send that runtime input through write().                                                                                      Like i mentioned above, in Qt console window, Output is displayed as "Enter Consumer No" but when i type no as "3234546577"  ,how to send this no to jar file

Comment: Use the standard C++ way to read console input, and pass that to the write function.

But why do you want that? You have a main window, aren't you trying to make a gui wrapper for your console application?

Comment: As you said, i tried standard C++ way to read console input and passed the same through write() ,and now i can execute the jar successfully, Next step is i need to display the same in GUI window. If i have doubt i will post you. Thanks in advance